# SSL real_connect returns null but the error code is 0

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, nginx, mysqli

I have a website server in which it should be possible to log in into a database. Both the server and the database are in the same machine, so the cominucations are thourgh localhost.

The problem is that I am trying to comunicate these elements with SSL enabled, for practice. In order to do this, I have a little code un PHP which should create the connection after setting the correct options. For the SSL part, I created my own CA and made two pairs of crts and keys: one pair for the nginx server and the another for the database.

When I try to make the connection, real_connect returns a null value but the errno is 0, so I don't know if there is an error in the code or it's something related to the SSL certicates.

If I try to make the connection without SSL there is no problem.

This is the PHP code that should handle the login:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>MariaDB Query</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php


$server="127.0.0.1";
$user=$_POST['user'];
$pwd=$_POST['pwd'];
$db="mydb";

$mysqli = mysqli_init();
if(!$mysqli){
die("mysqli failed");
}


$mysqli->ssl_set("/etc/mysql/ssl/mariadb.key", "/etc/mysql/ssl/mariadb_cert.pem", "/etc/nginx/server_files/rootCA.crt", NULL, NULL);

if(!$mysqli->real_connect($server, $user, $pwd, $db, null, null, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SLL)){
die("Connect Error:" . mysqli_connect_error() ." : ". mysqli_connect_errno());
} else {
echo 'SUCCESS';
}
$mysqli->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that both the user and the password are received from another website that handles the reception of these values (the classic website with two areas for input text).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: try using the `mysql` client with its ssl options and the same files to connect to the server. Are the file readable by the user the php script is running as?

Comment: I found a mismatch in the my.cnf file regarding the CA.crt path. I changed it and tried the SSL connection with the mysql client, It works. Following this, I changed the php file so it has the same SSL files as the ones in the mysql's SSL configuration, but I am still getting the same problem as before.

Comment: Which PHP version are you using? Is it PHP >=7.4.4?

Comment: Yes, I am using PHP 7.4.5